# CMake/Catkin: How to export imported target

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pre-compiled shared library **foo.so**, and I'd like to wrap it in a catkin package for use by other catkin packages. So far I can accomplish all the linking issues if **foo.so** is in the same package as the targets that use it, but I am unable to get other packages to find the library externally. I have the following lines:

```
add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/foo.so)
```

It compiles and runs great if in the same CMakeLists.txt I have something like:

```
add_library(bar src/bar.cpp}
target_link_libraries(bar
  foo
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

But if I put this **bar** library in a different catkin package, it compiles fine but at runtime I get linking errors that then say missing symbols:

```
symbol lookup error: foo.so: undefined symbol
```

I have been researching and playing with adding things such as

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS foo)
```

or

```
export(TARGET foo)
```

But I'm really over my head. **How do I export a pre-compiled shared library from one catkin package to another?** I'm using catkin-tools.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223866/cmake/catkin:-how-to-export-imported-target/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the help of @wjwwood we came up with this workaround solution that still seems reliable. From what I can tell, CMake does not have proper support for exporting or installing imported targets, as per [this discussion](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14311):

> Imported targets were originally designed for importing from an existing installation of some external package so installing did not make sense at the time.

**Our Solution:**

In the first package's CMakeLists.txt that contains the pre-compiled shared object that you want to share, you need the following. Note that in this example ${PROJECT_NAME} and "foo" must be the same name, since we are using ${PROJECT_NAME} as the name of the library. This can be changed though.

```
# Configure Locations
set(foo_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libfoo.so)
set(foo_DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.so)
MESSAGE( STATUS "foo_LOCATION:         " ${foo_LOCATION} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "foo_DESTINATION:      " ${foo_DESTINATION} )

# Foo library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${foo_LOCATION})

# Unfortuantly an imported target is not copied to the devel/lib folder, so we do it manually
# so that installation of a catkin workspace is not required
# See http://answers.ros.org/question/223866/cmakecatkin-how-to-export-imported-target/
file(COPY ${foo_LOCATION}
  DESTINATION ${foo_DESTINATION}
)


# Mark imported library for installation using a workaround since imported
# targets do not have proper support for installation in CMakeLists
install(FILES ${foo_LOCATION} DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})
```

And in the second packge's CMakeLists.txt the foo library is automatically linked using the normal

```
target_link_libraries(bar
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-12**:
A similar thing is done in the `prosilica_gige_sdk` package ([here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_gige_sdk/blob/ec45bac2631a5b9a1dc08b21fb1ae87147eff560/CMakeLists.txt#L149-L166)).

**Comment by [Mitch Woodside](https://answers.ros.org/users/50726/mitch-woodside/) on 2020-01-06**:
First of all, awesome work with this solution! I've been using this and the `prosilica_gige_sdk` to piece together a ROS package for a pre-compiled dll library on Windows. For lack of a better word, it has been... fun.

@Dave Coleman, quick question about your solution, what is the purpose of this section?

```
# Foo library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${foo_LOCATION})
```

Since you are copying the library files directly to the devel and install spaces, why do you need to create a CMAKE target for the imported library?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could copy also the foo lib since it is shared and bar need foo to run. Or you copy the foo lib in /usr/local/lib or you add the path of foe in the lib search path.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-01-11**:
this is what we kind of ended up doing, thanks!